# Extracting a ZIP folder bigger then my storage

Tags: windows, zip

So I was trying to extract a ZIP folder today, and I've came upon the most common problem: storage space. As an example, this is the error I'm getting:

> There is not enough space on Local Disk. You need an additional 9.88 GB to copy these files. Space Free: 40.6 GB Total Size: 237 GB

Now to start off, the ZIP file that I'm trying to extract is about 51.4 GB in size. I was wondering if anyone new any ways of how I can extract the ZIP folder, and delete the ZIP folder right afterwards? Because if I was to try to extract a ZIP folder the normal way, it would overflow my computer's storage space.

I've already tried a couple of things for this problem. I tried cleaning out a lot of my computer's storage, but the rest of the storage are apps that I need to keep on this computer. I can't get an external hard drive, because the best I have is a 7GB.

So I was looking if any of you have any programs or ideas of how I can extract this successfully? I do not have a budget for this, so I will not pay for anything. Just as a reminder, I want the extracted contents of the ZIP folder, and I do not want the ZIP folder after it's extracted.

Comment: Buy a new HDD .

Comment: Do you have disk compression turned on?